# Multiple images deleted from database but not from disc Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with Laravel 7 trying to delete multiple images from my app. When I hit the delete button, the images are removed successfully from the `show.blade.php` as well as from the database. However, they are still in my storage on my local disk. I am storing my images in `storage/app/public/upload` as well as the symlink pointing to `storage/upload` in the public directory under app. I have tried a variety of ways to get it to delete but nothing has been fruitful. I have my one to many relationships set up in my models which I will show below. I need this to work under three circumstances such as if there is no image, one image or many images. I am using Laravel Resources for my routing and so my `TaskController.php` only has one destroy method.

Here is the code I have so far:
Models -
Image.php (relevant functions only - Storage and Task classes imported at top)

```
public function task()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Task', 'task_id');
        // return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
    }

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::deleting(function ($images) {

            Storage::delete(Storage::path($images['name']));
        });
    }
```

Task.php (relevant code only - Storage, File and Image classes imported at top)

```
public function images()
    {
        // return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
    }

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::deleting(function ($task) {
            foreach ($task->images ?: [] as $image) {
                $image->delete();
            }
        });
    }
```

Controller
TasksController.php (store, show, update and destroy)

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'task_name' => 'required',
            'task_description' => 'required',
        ]);

        // Create Task
        $user = Auth::user();
        $task = new Task();
        $data = $request->all();
        $task->user_id = $user->id;
        $task = $user->task()->create($data);
        if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
            $files = $request->file('images');
            foreach ($files ?: [] as $file) {
                $name = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $name = str_replace(' ', '-', $name);
                $file->storeAs('public/upload', $name);
                $task->images()->create(['name' => $name]);
                $images = new Image;
                $images->name = $name;
            }
        }
        $task->task_name = $request->input('task_name');
        $task->task_description = $request->input('task_description');
        $task->task_priority = $request->input('task_priority');
        $task->task_assigned_by = $request->input('task_assigned_by');
        $task->task_assigned_to = $request->input('task_assigned_to');
        $task->task_to_be_completed_date = $request->input('task_to_be_completed_date');
        $task->task_notes = $request->input('task_notes');
        $task->task_status = $request->task_status;
        $task->save();



        return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'Task Created');
    }
    
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'task_name' => 'required',
            'task_description' => 'required',
        ]);


        $task = Task::find($id);
        $task->task_name = $request->input('task_name');
        $task->task_description = $request->input('task_description');
        $task->task_priority = $request->input('task_priority');
        $task->task_assigned_by = $request->input('task_assigned_by');
        $task->task_assigned_to = $request->input('task_assigned_to');
        $task->task_to_be_completed_date = $request->input('task_to_be_completed_date');
        $task->task_notes = $request->input('task_notes');
        $task->task_status = $request->input('task_status');
        if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
            $files = $request->file('images');
            foreach ($files ?: [] as $file) {
                $name = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $name = str_replace(' ', '-', $name);
                $file->storeAs('public/upload', $name);
                $task->images()->create(['name' => $name]);
                $images = new Image;
                $images->name = $name;
            }
        }
        $task->save();
        return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'Task Updated');
    }
    public function show($id)
    {
        $task =  Task::find($id);
        return view('tasks.show')->with('task', $task);
    }
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $task = Task::findOrFail($id);
        $images = Image::find($id);

        $images = explode(',', $images['name']);

        foreach ($images as $image) {
            // $path = 'storage/app/public/upload/' . $image;
            if (file_exists('../storage/app/public/upload/' . json_decode($image, true)['name'])) {
                // print_r('file found');
                // unlink('../storage/app/public/upload/' . base64_decode($image, true)['name']);
                // dd('../storage/app/public/upload/' . json_decode($image, true)['name']);
                // File::delete('../storage/app/public/upload/' . json_decode($image, true)['name']);
                dd('../storage/app/public/upload/' . $task['image']);
                File::delete('../storage/app/public/upload/' . json_decode($image, true)['name'] . $task['images']);
            } else {
                print_r('no sirve ' . __DIR__ . ' ' . $image . var_dump($image));
            }
            // dd($path);
            // if (File::exists($path)) {
            //     File::delete($path);
            // }
        }


        // $task->delete();
        return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Task Deleted');
    }
```

I have left some commented code included so you can see what I have tried. If I am missing anything, please let me know and I will edit my question.
Thank you in advance for your help. I have been stuck on this for a week.

EDIT
I have changed my destroy function. It still does not delete the files from the disk. Here is the function:

```
 public function destroy($id)
{
    // $task = Task::findOrFail($id);
    $task = Task::with('images')->findOrFail($id);

    // $images = Image::find($id);

    // $images = $task->images($id)->get();

    foreach ($task->images as $image) {
        // dd(storage_path('app/public/upload/' . $image['name']));
        Storage::delete(storage_path('app/public/upload/' . $image->name));
    }

    $task->images()->delete();
    $task->delete();
    return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Task Deleted');
}
```

Comment: in my code im using `if file_exists(storage_path('image/filename')) then unlink(storage_path('image/filename'));'

Comment: Thank you Alzafan. I tried that but it came back with a permission denied error. Any clues as to why?
`unlink(C:\laragon\www\taskapp\storage\../storage/app/public/upload): Permission denied
`

Comment: no, replace `../storage` as  `storage_path()` return path to `app/storage` or use `public_path('path_to_file')` return `app/public` path

Comment: I ran `if (file_exists(public_path('storage/upload/' . json_decode($image, true)['name']))) {
                dd(public_path('storage/upload/' . json_decode($image, true)['name']));
                
                File::delete(storage_path(json_decode($image, true)['name']));
            } `
and got a dd of:
`"C:\laragon\www\taskapp\public\storage/upload/"`

Comment: there you got a clue to the path, just set the path to the symlink(shortcut folder in app/public) or direct to `storage_path`

Comment: after that, based on my code, I am unclear how to access the individual file names. when I try, I get null as a response

Comment: you should delete the file first then the data

Comment: I still cannot access my actual file names for some reason. I edited my question with the new destroy function.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up calling the public folder for the delete function using `Storage::disk('public')->delete('upload/' . $image->name);`
That in the end helped me to delete the files from my disk. I hope this helps anyone who faces the same issue. Thank you Alzafan Christian for your help in this. You led me in the right direction.